Warning message when using map_df to read .txt files "line appears to contain embedded nulls"
I'm working with a loop that reads .txt files in different folders through the map_df function, but for some folders only there's the warning message "line 'x' appears to contain embedded nulls". There's a similar post here with csv files, but I tried their solutions and it didn't work either.
I first made a list of the files in the folder, then I joined multiple strings into a single string and then I used the map_df to map each file.
It seems that there's also a problem with the 'read.delim' part.
-
I already tried adding 'encoding=UTF-8', or the fileEncoding, but then I get the error
"Error in map():
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in read.table():
! unused argument (id = "data_source")"
Here's my original code:
 pwd2 <-(paste0(pwd, "/", sprintf("%02d", pnum)))
  setwd(pwd2)

files <- list.files(path = pwd2, pattern='.txt')

files <- str_c(files)

data <- map_df(.x=files, .f=read.delim, .id='data_source')

Tried adding 'encoding=UTF-8', or the fileEncoding argument, but then I get the error
"Error in map():
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in read.table():
! unused argument (id = "data_source")"

From shared file samples there seem to be more than one issue.

those are not quite regular tabular text files, each of those reports starts with a meta-data section (4+1 rows) and it looks like there's separate section for summary statistics. You have most likely handled this in your code, I'm just skipping first 5 rows here for simplicity

Full Name   "tdcs&gait_10min, 006  "                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Test Time   2024-02-14 18:03                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Reference                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Memo    Walk5_anodal                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        First Contact (sec.)    Last Contact (sec.) Integ. Pressure (p x sec.)  Foot Length (cm.)   Foot Length %   Foot Width (cm.)    Foot Area (cm. x cm.)   Foot Angle (degrees)    Toe In/Out Angle (degrees)  Foot Toe X Location (cm.)   Foot Toe Y Location (cm.)   Foot Heel X Location (cm.)  Foot Heel Y Location (cm.)  Step Length (cm.)   Absolute Step Length (cm.)  Stride Length (cm.) Stride Width (cm.)  Step Time (sec.)    Stride Time (sec.)  Stride Velocity (cm./sec.)  DOP (degrees)   Gait Cycle Time (sec.)  Stance Time (sec.)  Stance %    Swing Time (sec.)   Swing % Single Support (sec.)   Single Support %    Initial D. Support (sec.)   Initial D. Support %    Terminal D. Support (sec.)  Terminal D. Support %   Total D. Support (sec.) Total D. Support %  CISP Time (sec.)    CISP AP (%) CISP ML (%) Stance COP Dist. (cm.)  SS COP Dist. (cm.)  DS COP Dist. (cm.)  Stance COP Dist. %  SS COP Dist. %  Stance COP Path Eff. %  SS COP Path Eff. %  DS COP Path Eff.%   Velocity (cm./sec.) Ambulation Time (sec.)  Cadence (steps/min.)    FAP
#Samples        53  53  53  53  53  53  53  53  37  53  53  53  53  37  37  37  37  37  37  37  37  37  53  37  37  37  36  28  45  29  45  37  37  29  19  19  19  53  36  45  53  36  53  36  45              
#Samples    Left    26  26  26  26  26  26  26  26  18  26  26  26  26  18  18  18  18  18  18  18  18  18  26  18  18  18  19  16  24  16  21  18  19  16  9   9   9   26  19  21  26  19  26  19  21              
#Samples    Right   27  27  27  27  27  27  27  27  19  27  27  27  27  19  19  19  19  19  19  19  19  19  27  19  19  19  17  12  21  13  24  19  18  13  10  10  10  27  17  24  27  17  27  17  24              
/.../
1   1: Right 1  3.058   3.708   142.108 32.973  96.786  11.196  289.954 -6.755  2.575   87.702  26.88   54.958  30.758  67.242  68.168  138.273 11.202  0.5 1   138.273 -4.18   1   0.658   65.833  0.342   34.167                  0.158   15.833                      30.654      60.446  89.98       98.261      99.998              
2   Left 1  3.558   4.192   135.05  32.079  93.224  11.06   278.664 1.535   3.527   158.685 37.611  126.617 36.752  67.198  68.593  133.963 13.761  0.475   0.975   137.398 -1.992  0.975   0.642   65.812  0.333   34.188  0.342   35.043  0.158   16.239  0.142   14.53   0.3 30.769              27.991  10.114  57.792  81.344  29.393  97.244  98.873  99.993              
3   Right 2 4.058   4.683   161.742 31.878  93.571  11.264  282.021 -7.071  7.344   224.499 16.755  192.863 20.679  67.537  68.443  135.227 11.094  0.492   0.967   139.89  0.273   0.967   0.633   65.517  0.333   34.483  0.333   34.483  0.142   14.655  0.158   16.379  0.3 31.034  4.617   10.714  -4.109  28.558  8.413   58.778  83.826  24.696  99.434  99.161  99.99               


some files are UTF-16LE encoded (perhaps those were opened in some editor?)
some files seem to include corrupt records, those are changing column types from numeric to character

36  Right 2 39.467  40.117  160.408 29.1    85.418  11.378  260.043 174.346 7.502   302.157 27.318  331.115 24.451  63.811  64.49   133.131 9.336   0.492   0.983   135.387 -178.151    0.983   0.658   66.949  0.325   33.051  0.333   33.898  0.158   16.102  0.167   16.949  0.325   33.051  40.033  2.495   -18.981 27.953  7.228   61.161  82.05   21.216  97.762  97.989  99.993              
37  Left 2  ^#39.958    ^#40.967    ^#110.825   ^#30.447    ^#88.481    ^#12.347    ^#295.249   ^#-176.867  ^#2.595 ^#231.731   ^#11.220    ^#262.133   ^#12.884    ^#71.779    ^#72.209    ^#135.786   ^#7.874 ^#0.492 ^#0.983 ^#138.088   ^#-179.462  ^#0.983 ^#1.017 ^#103.390   ^#-0.033    ^#-3.390    ^#0.325 ^#33.051    ^#0.167 ^#16.949    ^#0.525 ^#53.390    ^#0.725 ^#73.729                ^#135.851   ^#9.957 ^#75.486    ^#394.790   ^#28.937    ^#78.806    ^#99.179    ^#97.179                
38  Right 3 40.45   41.092  147.608 34.026  99.876  11.294  301.812 173.001 4.005   164.282 24.302  198.054 20.156  62.62   63.813  133.777 12.281  0.475   0.967   138.39  177.005 0.967   0.65    67.241  0.317   32.759          0.525   54.31   0.158   16.379  0.683   70.69               29.227      58.668  85.789      96.782      99.999              
39  Left 3  ^#40.942    ^#41.575    ^#106.967   ^#29.425    ^#85.511    ^#12.013    ^#277.634   ^#-178.976      ^#96.932    ^#11.084    ^#126.352   ^#11.609                                        ^#0.642             ^#0.317     ^#0.033     ^#0.167     ^#0.358                 ^#66.040    ^#8.548 ^#56.280    ^#191.916   ^#24.840    ^#86.340    ^#94.802    ^#99.997                

We can guess file encodings with readr::guess_encoding() and load files in batches, separated by their encoding.
library(readr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

# guess encodings
guessed_encodings <- 
  fs::dir_ls("./", recurse = TRUE, glob = "*.txt") |>
  map(guess_encoding, n_max = -1, threshold = .5) |>
  list_rbind(names_to = "file")

guessed_encodings
#> # A tibble: 72 × 3
#>    file                       encoding confidence
#>    <chr>                      <chr>         <dbl>
#>  1 01/001Baseline1_anodal.txt ASCII             1
#>  2 01/001Baseline1_sham.txt   ASCII             1
#>  3 01/001Baseline2_anodal.txt ASCII             1
#>  4 01/001Baseline2_sham.txt   ASCII             1
#>  5 01/001Baseline3_anodal.txt ASCII             1
#>  6 01/001Baseline3_sham.txt   UTF-16LE          1
#>  7 01/001Walk1_anodal.txt     ASCII             1
#>  8 01/001Walk1_sham.txt       ASCII             1
#>  9 01/001Walk2_anodal.txt     ASCII             1
#> 10 01/001Walk2_sham.txt       ASCII             1
#> # ℹ 62 more rows

# check counts
table(guessed_encodings$encoding)
#> 
#>    ASCII UTF-16LE 
#>       68        4

# read ASCII files, skip meta-data rows(5)
df_ascii <- 
  guessed_encodings |>
  filter(encoding == "ASCII") |>
  pull(file) |>
  read_tsv(id = "data_source", skip = 5, show_col_types = FALSE)
#> New names:
#> • `` -> `...1`
#> • `` -> `...2`
#> Warning: One or more parsing issues, call `problems()` on your data frame for details,
#> e.g.:
#>   dat <- vroom(...)
#>   problems(dat)

# there's a warning and many dbl columns are turned into chr ...
df_ascii
#> # A tibble: 4,621 × 52
#>    data_source          ...1  ...2  `First Contact (sec.)` `Last Contact (sec.)`
#>    <chr>                <chr> <chr> <chr>                  <chr>                
#>  1 01/001Baseline1_ano… #Sam… <NA>  55                     55                   
#>  2 01/001Baseline1_ano… #Sam… Left  27                     27                   
#>  3 01/001Baseline1_ano… #Sam… Right 28                     28                   
#>  4 01/001Baseline1_ano… Mean  <NA>  39.066                 39.763               
#>  5 01/001Baseline1_ano… Mean  Left  37.479                 38.176               
#>  6 01/001Baseline1_ano… Mean  Right 40.597                 41.294               
#>  7 01/001Baseline1_ano… Ratio L/R   0.923                  0.924                
#>  8 01/001Baseline1_ano… S.D.  <NA>  23.138                 23.129               
#>  9 01/001Baseline1_ano… S.D.  Left  22.523                 22.513               
#> 10 01/001Baseline1_ano… S.D.  Right 24.027                 24.018               
#> # ℹ 4,611 more rows
#> # ℹ 47 more variables: `Integ. Pressure (p x sec.)` <chr>,
#> #   `Foot Length (cm.)` <chr>, `Foot Length %` <chr>, `Foot Width (cm.)` <chr>,
#> #   `Foot Area (cm. x cm.)` <chr>, `Foot Angle (degrees)` <chr>,
#> #   `Toe In/Out Angle (degrees)` <dbl>, `Foot Toe X Location (cm.)` <chr>,
#> #   `Foot Toe Y Location (cm.)` <chr>, `Foot Heel X Location (cm.)` <chr>,
#> #   `Foot Heel Y Location (cm.)` <chr>, `Step Length (cm.)` <dbl>, …

# let's check those issues  
problems(df_ascii) |>
  mutate(file = tibble::char(file, shorten = "front"))
#> # A tibble: 34 × 5
#>      row   col expected actual     file                                         
#>    <int> <int> <chr>    <chr>      <char>                                       
#>  1    51    11 a double ^#2.595    …oads/Send-Archive/06/006Baseline2_anodal.txt
#>  2    51    16 a double ^#71.779   …oads/Send-Archive/06/006Baseline2_anodal.txt
#>  3    51    17 a double ^#72.209   …oads/Send-Archive/06/006Baseline2_anodal.txt
#>  4    51    18 a double ^#135.786  …oads/Send-Archive/06/006Baseline2_anodal.txt
#>  5    51    19 a double ^#7.874    …oads/Send-Archive/06/006Baseline2_anodal.txt
#>  6    51    20 a double ^#0.492    …oads/Send-Archive/06/006Baseline2_anodal.txt
#>  7    51    21 a double ^#0.983    …oads/Send-Archive/06/006Baseline2_anodal.txt
#>  8    51    22 a double ^#138.088  …oads/Send-Archive/06/006Baseline2_anodal.txt
#>  9    51    23 a double ^#-179.462 …oads/Send-Archive/06/006Baseline2_anodal.txt
#> 10    51    24 a double ^#0.983    …oads/Send-Archive/06/006Baseline2_anodal.txt
#> # ℹ 24 more rows

# check one of those reported problems, line 51 (skipped 5, 1 for header: +6)
# middle one, 51(57), looks like a corrupt record? 
read_lines(problems(df_ascii)$file[1]) |>
    str_trunc(60) |>
    str_view() |>
    _[50:52+6]
#> [56] │ 36{\t}Right 2{\t}39.467{\t}40.117{\t}160.408{\t}29.1{\t}85.418{\t}11.378{\t}260.0...
#> [57] │ 37{\t}Left 2{\t}^#39.958{\t}^#40.967{\t}^#110.825{\t}^#30.447{\t}^#88.481{\t}^...
#> [58] │ 38{\t}Right 3{\t}40.45{\t}41.092{\t}147.608{\t}34.026{\t}99.876{\t}11.294{\t}301....

# read UTF-16LE files, those must be read one at a time
# (Error: Reading files of encoding 'UTF-16LE' can only be done for single files at a time)
df_16le <- 
  guessed_encodings |>
  filter(encoding == "UTF-16LE") |>
  pull(file) |>
  set_names() |>
  map(read_tsv, locale = locale(encoding = "UTF-16LE"), 
      skip = 5, show_col_types = FALSE) |>
  list_rbind(names_to = "data_source")
#> New names:
#> New names:
#> New names:
#> New names:
#> • `` -> `...1`
#> • `` -> `...2`

df_16le
#> # A tibble: 257 × 52
#>    data_source          ...1  ...2  `First Contact (sec.)` `Last Contact (sec.)`
#>    <chr>                <chr> <chr>                  <dbl>                 <dbl>
#>  1 01/001Baseline3_sha… #Sam… <NA>                   47                    47   
#>  2 01/001Baseline3_sha… #Sam… Left                   22                    22   
#>  3 01/001Baseline3_sha… #Sam… Right                  25                    25   
#>  4 01/001Baseline3_sha… Mean  <NA>                   37.4                  38.1 
#>  5 01/001Baseline3_sha… Mean  Left                   39.8                  40.5 
#>  6 01/001Baseline3_sha… Mean  Right                  35.3                  36.0 
#>  7 01/001Baseline3_sha… Ratio L/R                     1.13                  1.12
#>  8 01/001Baseline3_sha… S.D.  <NA>                   24.0                  24.0 
#>  9 01/001Baseline3_sha… S.D.  Left                   24.9                  24.9 
#> 10 01/001Baseline3_sha… S.D.  Right                  23.4                  23.4 
#> # ℹ 247 more rows
#> # ℹ 47 more variables: `Integ. Pressure (p x sec.)` <dbl>,
#> #   `Foot Length (cm.)` <dbl>, `Foot Length %` <dbl>, `Foot Width (cm.)` <dbl>,
#> #   `Foot Area (cm. x cm.)` <dbl>, `Foot Angle (degrees)` <dbl>,
#> #   `Toe In/Out Angle (degrees)` <dbl>, `Foot Toe X Location (cm.)` <dbl>,
#> #   `Foot Toe Y Location (cm.)` <dbl>, `Foot Heel X Location (cm.)` <dbl>,
#> #   `Foot Heel Y Location (cm.)` <dbl>, `Step Length (cm.)` <dbl>, …


Original revision, before file samples - https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/78577029/2

Hi @margusl thank you for your answer! Yes, you're right, I was adding the point before the id, just forgot to add to the code here. Your code seems to work partially for what I need, because when using the read_delim instead of the read.delim(), it changes the structure of my df, so it seems I'll need to use the map_df as before. What's weird is that for some folders it works but for other it doesn't.

Update: I managed to make it work with your code (the read_delim) changing some other things in my code, but then again the same folders are giving me problem and now the warning message is "Error: Could not guess the delimiter."

To make it easier, I uploaded some of the files here: https://send.vis.ee/download/3437ce9c7b94d60e/#ejiFbx_XHRD5cbhOg54dmwwhere one of the folders (03) works good but the other one with folders 1,5,6 don't work and give me those warning messages.

@banzecoleco , played around with those files a bit and updated my asnwer, not quite a 2-liner anymore :) You probably have some digging to do on why some files end up being UTF16LE (my guess is those were opened with some editor / tool). And there are few records that I'd consider corrupt, but there might some other explanation, related to this specific piece of equipment or software that generates those reports.
